# Is it possible to set a static external IP address in Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-shell

I'm using Cloud Shell within [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com) to connect to my Google Cloud Datalab GCE VM using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts). I have a firewall on my Google Cloud Datalab GCE VM that restricts SSH access to certain IP addresses only. The problem I have is that the cloud shell IP address changes frequently. Is it possible to set a static external IP address for Cloud Shell, or is there a list of IP ranges that will be used for cloud shell machines? I'm open to other suggestions about how to connect via ssh to a GCE VM with restricted firewall within cloud shell as well.

Comment: Please see my answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can set static external IP of your VM. Please follow following link of google documentation for same.

   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses

Go to Section "Reserving a new static external IP address".

I have tried it previously an 6 months back it works smoothly.

2. Even if  VM change IP external so often .
   Solution :-It should be better to have a Domain Name for that VM. i.e. even if IP changes beneath it ( Dynamic DNS server)  would handle it. Search for Dynamic DNS it would helpful.

But in your no. 2 won't be  valid as your firewall would block it anyways.

Comment: My understanding is that these instuctions are for compute engine resources and not for Cloud  Shell.

Comment: This will not work for Cloud Shell, these instructions are for VMs

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions about how to connect via ssh to a GCE VM with restricted firewall within cloud shell as well. :- To answer this question you can directly ssh through "putty" to VM , by giving VM "Static external IP address" . Which fits your needs "Simple".

Comment: "...within cloud shell". I need to set a static IP in Cloud Shell

Comment: why do you need "cloud shell static IP " ... you have to understand how your google shell works. Google shell is just hosted on a "temporary VM or a Server" --> which is running a server code ( taking commands from jquery browser)  for  replicating commands & sending it to over your actual "hosted VM."

Comment: This is a legitimate need. In highly secured/regulated environments, resources are often restricted by firewall rules to incoming connections from whitelisted IP addresses only. There is currently no way to add Cloud Shell to a whitelist like this without whitelisting virtually all of Google's IP space, which is enormous. Cloud Shell would be an outstanding solution to act as a client to such resources because of it's fully managed and tightly secured nature, but it *can't* be used in these scenarios because of the inability to fix an IP address.

Answer (score 4):

Recommendation here is leverage a bastion host that you allow access to. Cloudshell ssh there, then interact with the environment. Its a pain, believe me. Alternatively you can whitelist all of googles published external ranges associated with gcp, but you pick up the random users of services as well. Good luck.